# Set WinEdt background color as Monokai

Tags: winedt

My eyes get tired when using the given Background schemes in WinEdt, and I found Sublime text color theme Monokai is quite good. How can I set this color in WinEdt?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It would be helpful to know, which *version* of WinEdt you are using.

Comment: Hi Stefan, My current version is WinEdt 9.1

Answer (score 4):

If you are using WinEdt 10, you can choose some predefined themes from `options` -> `themes` menu.

For example, the `Solarized Dark` looks like:

[image]

Comment: My current version is WinEdt 9.1, and I found there does not exist Solarized Dark theme. Which means I need to upgrade my WinEdt?

Comment: These themes I think are available only in WinEdt 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some themes for WinEdt 9.x here:

http://www.winedt.org/old/Config/menus/Themes.php

pg

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It is very useful