# Winedt 10. How to use a theme in all Winedt and not only in a sub-window?

Tags: winedt, themes

after selecting Options / Theme / Solarized Dark you can see this
[image]

The question is: How to obtain all Winedt Window (menus, optioins interface, Tree, console idle, toolbar,...) afected by Solarized theme (or other) ?, if it were possible.

Comment: I have the same problem. Hopefully, someone helps...

Comment: @Leo I´m still in the same situation. There´s an option but it´s not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Alex told me that "it possible to apply text color and background color to docked
controls (Tree, Console, etc...). This can be done by modifying two
lines in SolarizedDark.ini:

```
// Forms (Tree, Console, Gather...)
fclFormBk="SysNone" // "RGB_7"
fclFormText="SysNone" //"RGB_3"
```

to

```
fclFormBk="RGB_7"
fclFormText="RGB_3"
```

But after doing so selected items in the tree will become almost
invisible because it is not possible to change the selected
attributes inside this control. That's why defaults don't use these
colors.

Will this change in the future? Not likely"

P.D.- Please, let me know your advances or your opinion about the results.

Comment: Is SolarizedDark.ini a file in Program Files/WinEdt Team/WinEdt 10.0, or is it an option in the WinEdt program?

Comment: @Leo it´s a file "c:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 10\ConfigEx\Themes\Solarized Dark.ini"  added. I have:  Easy Gray.ini ,
Midnight Black.ini ,
Midnight Blue.ini ,
Midnight Green.ini ,
Solarized Dark.ini ,
Solarized Light.ini ,
z_Solarized Dark.ini

Comment: @Leo You can choose SolarizedDark, I think, in WinEdt10, in options / Themes / .... Yo can see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343837/set-winedt-background-color-as-monokai/344604

Comment: @Leo or Ctrl+F theme or Solarized at the log of WinEdt for more info: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343837/set-winedt-background-color-as-monokai/344604 Please, let me now your improvements :-)

Comment: Yessss, it works now! :) Thank you very much. And apologies for the late reply. Best regards!

Comment: @leo WinEdt11 have the SolarizedDark as an them option in Options/Theme