# Is it possible to customize the colors of console, etc of WinEdt 11?

Tags: winedt, themes, customize

Is it possible to customize the colors of console, options interface, autocompletion list, etc. in WinEdt 11?

[image]

Comment: You should probably peruse WinEdt's support options: https://www.winedt.com/support.html I don't think this is a LaTeX issue as such.

Comment: Also, asked and answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452463/